Spring post request keeps saying: "Invalid username or password"
I'm trying to make a login system with Spring. Now the users are created with the hashed passwords and a token should be generated if the login is correct. I'm testing in Postman and I see that it's correct and that it generates a token (if I debug), but still it always gives back the "Invalid username or password" and it doesn't return the token...
This are some parts of my code
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );

            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(userDetails);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthResponse(token));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}

class AuthRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

class AuthResponse {
    private String token;

    public AuthResponse(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}

   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtFilter jwtFilter) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll() // Login endpoint vrij toegankelijk
                        .requestMatchers("/posts", "/posts/**").permitAll() // Openbare endpoints
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }

        System.out.println("Found user: " + user.getUsername() + ", with hashed password: " + user.getPassword());


        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getRoleName()))
        );
    }
}


Does anyone know what could be the cause?
So in the end it says it's generating a token, but doesn't return anything and says the username or password is incorrect...

As first hypothesis, you may have an error in the configuration of the AuthenticationManager where the encoding of the password doesn't match the way it was encoded when saved in your repository... debug your PasswordEncoder with a break point in matches()

The AuthenticationManager delegates to the AuthenticationProvider.  Have you configured an AuthenticationProvider bean to use your UserDetailsService and password encoder?
